# Load page title initial automatically

Tags: asp.net

today:

on every page "load" event-

```
Page.Title = defaultPageTitle + Page.Title;
```

"defaultPageTitle"- String that is taken from "basePage",
that means that for every new page, I have to copy&paste this line.

my goal: automatically load initial title suffix to every page..

defaultPageTitle="XXX- "
so if my aspx code file title tag is `<title>page1</title>`

the page title will be "XXX- page1"

Comment: Are you using a `MasterPage`? Then you could use it's `Page_load` event and the `Page` property. If not, you could let all pages inherit from a common base page that does this.

Comment: what is the base page, Is every page inherits from this base page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is good practice to create a base class called PageBase which inherits from System.Web.UI.Page. Then inherit all your aspx pages from this base class. In this way you can refactor all your common code to the base class.

You can then override OnLoad event in the pagebase and move your code to this event. Then you need not to write this code in each page.

Other option is if you are using Master page, then you write your code to set the page title in the Page_Load event of the master page